# Dax- How to make a If Statement with multiple results for one condtions

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, powerbi, dax, row-level-security

i trying to programm some row level secruity in SSAS with Dax funtions.

my idea is that one employee can see the data from more than he can see.
I this case Bob can see his data, but also the data his Collegue Lars can see.
We created a Fact-view-table where we attached a domainname so its easier for us to filter in the RLS

```
=Sales[DomainName]= IF(USERNAME()="Bob",{"Bob","Lars"},USERNAME())
```

But if i wanna test via PowerBi hes says

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was
> expected

what did i forget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor this as

```
IF (
    USERNAME() = "Bob",
    Sales[DomainName] IN {"Bob","Lars"},
    Sales[DomainName] = USERNAME()
)
```